# How to revert a wrong Git pull (remote to local)

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I pull a wrong remote branch to local i.e Merge branch 'remote' of ://github.../remote into Local

A right click in TortoiseGit -> Revert changes by this commit is requesting to revert to either "parent 1" or "parent 2". I simply want to cancel the pull remote into local, what should chose ?

Comment: Don't revert. Revert means something else. It writes a new commit reversing all the changes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the original commit your branch was on before you pulled.

`ORIG_HEAD` points to the original head of a branch before it was changed in a drastic way. "Drastic" means something more than a simple commit, like `git reset` or `git pull`. Verify `ORIG_HEAD` points at your pre-pull commit with `git log ORIG_HEAD`.

If it isn't, you can use `git log --graph --decorate` to find the commit before the pull. Or you can use `git reflog` to look at where HEAD was every time it changed.

2. Reset the branch.

Assuming it's `ORIG_HEAD`: `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`

This will move the branch back to the specified commit as if the pull never happened.